# Python time.time() returns wrong value

Tags: python

I need the UNIX epoch timestamp. I'm working with time.time(), but it returns me a value, which is exactly 8 hours off target time. It's not my local timezone either, because I'm it would be UTC+2. But the date and time of the Raspberry Pi is correct and whenever I manually try it, it returns the correct timestamp.

Comment: Could you include the exact code you used, the output, and the time you expected to see? (probably `date +%s` in the terminal will give you that)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it. The problem was that I get the output with PHP from a MySQL-Database and was exporting around 81'486 values. That took more memory than the allowed 128MB. I raised the memory for PHP to 256MB and that solved the problem.

Never thought that the data would take this much memory...